# Why is my text string rendered as a solid/filled rectangle in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So I made a "Yo Mama" joke generator, and it does what it should be doing (It works if I delete all the Pygame-specific code and print it to the terminal/command line). But when I add Pygame and make an application, it shows me the text as a white rectangle. Visual Studio doesn't give me any errors, but the text is seen as a white rectangle. Take a look at [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xCoC.jpg)

```
import random
import pygame
import os 
from yo_mama_jokes import da_jokes 
pygame.font.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 750,750
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Your mama joke generator")


def main():
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 20)
    run = True
    joke = random.choice(da_jokes)
    while run:
        label = myfont.render(joke, 1, (255,255,255))
        WIN.blit(label, (15, 350))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
main()
```

Comment: Does it have the same behavior when you replace `joke` with a literal string? And what does `pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 20, constructor=print)` echo for you?

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing when i write anything (strings, etc.). Also, when I use the construtor=print, it gives me this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render'

Comment: Yes, that is expected that it raises an error. But what does it print in addition? You don't even need the rest of the code afterwards, just that line would be interesting

Comment: Have you tried `WIN.fill(0)`? (right before `WIN.blit(label, (15, 350))`)

Comment: This question is possible related to [Blitting text with pygame2.1 not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445036/blitting-text-with-pygame2-1-not-working-correctly/70447991#70447991)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `, pygame.SRCALPHA)` after `(255,255,255)`.

`SRCALPHA` creates an empty pixel alpha surface. The surface will now draw transparency if the color contains the fourth alpha value

This way the text will not be seen as a white rectangle when I add Pygame and create an application. You will have transparent every pixel of the surface:

```
import random
import pygame
import os 
from yo_mama_jokes import da_jokes 
pygame.font.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 750,750
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Your mama joke generator")


def main():
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 20)
    run = True
    joke = random.choice(da_jokes)
    while run:
        label = myfont.render(joke, 1, (255,255,255), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        WIN.blit(label, (15, 350))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
main()
```

Comment: Even if the answer is accepted, it is still wrong. [`pygame.font.Font.render`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) cannot deal with the `pygame.SRCALPHA` flag. Please read the documentation. The problem in the question is with the system, but not with the code. `render` always creates a _Surface_ with a transparent background (except you set a solid background). `pygame.SRCALPHA` is only for the use with [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `pygame.SRCALPHA` flag to give your text a transparent background:

```py
label = myfont.render(joke, 1, (255,255,255), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

**Edit:**
This code is actually using a *black* background behind the text. The 4th argument of `render` takes a color for the background, and since it doesn't recognize the `pygame.SRCALPHA` flag, it sets the background to black. This works in your situation, but will not work if you have a multicolored background.

Comment: My apologies, using `pygame.SRCALPHA` is actually setting a black background, which just appears transparent in this example.

Comment: Thanks, I will add that to the edit

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not your code but your system. Your code works fine:

[image]

```py
import pygame 
pygame.font.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 750,750
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Your mama joke generator")

background = pygame.Surface(WIN.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *background.get_size(), (128, 128, 128), (64, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
[pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect) for rect, color in tiles]

def main():
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 100)
    run = True
    joke = "Joke"
    while run:
        WIN.blit(background, (0, 0))
        label = myfont.render(joke, 1, (255,255,255))
        WIN.blit(label, (15, 350))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
main()
```

---

Note, that there is a known bug in the MacOS version of Pygame 2.1.0. [`fill(0)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill). does not work correctly and must be replaced with `fill((0, 0, 0))`. This bug will be fixed in Pygame 2.1.1.
See [Fix weird MacOS display surf weirdness #2859](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2859).