# Blitting text with pygame2.1 not working correctly

Tags: python, pygame

I’m having some problems trying to blit text with pygame2.1.

Here’s some reproducible code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 50)
text = font.render("Test", True, (255, 255, 255))
text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(250, 250))

run = True
while run:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    win.fill(0)
    win.blit(text, text_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Blitting directly on the main window doesen’t seem to function as expected.[image]

---

But strangely enough, blitting the text on a second surface, and then blitting the surface itself on the main window does work!

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
surf2 = pygame.Surface((400, 400))

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 50)
text = font.render("Test", True, (255, 255, 255))
text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(200, 200))

run = True
while run:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    win.fill(0)
    surf2.fill((128, 128, 128))
    surf2.blit(text, text_rect)
    win.blit(surf2, (50, 50))
    pygame.display.update()
```

[image]

I don’t get why that’s the case. Is it a bug in pygame, or just a problem with my computer?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem with the pygame version. It's likely a font problem. The 2nd version runs on a different system. Is the font file available on this system? Will pygame 2.1.0 work on your system? Anyway if there is a bug in the pygame version we cannot help you here.

Comment: I have tried loading the font directly from a file too… on my system as well. Still no luck.

Comment: Well, I guess this is a problem with macOS, I’m running Sierra, and my friend’s on BigSur.  Seems to work fine when i try it in replit.

Comment: Hey @Rabbid76, It seemed to be a problem with the flag `pygame.SRCALPHA`, removed it now and it works fine on both versions of pygame. Anyways, Thanks for your time!

Comment: Likely you're confused by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70264204/why-is-my-text-string-rendered-as-a-solid-filled-rectangle-in-pygame/70269323#70269323. This answer is wrong.

Comment: @Rabbid76, not quite so. I was able to narrow down the problem, and have edited my original post accordingly. Please have a look, and sorry if this is all over the place…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue is that alpha blending is kind of broken in the default blitter, i.e. using `special_flags=0`, the default. With the default blitter, if the *destination* surface has an alpha value of 0, then the source value will be used anyway *even if the source's alpha value is 0*.

Now, when you use `win.fill(0)`, this doesn't just set r, g, b values to 0, but also the alpha value. Now, the text is a transparent alpha surface, that you blit onto this surface. But since the alpha of the target surface is 0 (because of the fill), so the alpha values of the source text surface are entirely ignored, and it just gets blitted on as a solid white rectangle.

There are a few fixes possible.

#### Option 1: change `fill` command

as alluded to in another answer: don't use `.fill(0)`, but use e.g. `.fill((0, 0, 0))`. This way, you don't set the alpha value too.

#### Option 2: fix broken alpha value

Fix the broken alpha value on the target surface by doing:

```
win.fill((0, 0, 0, 255), text_rect, pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MAX)
```

This will increase alpha everywhere on the window, without changing any of the colors.

Or if you want, you can do this just for the text rectangle:

```
win.fill((0, 0, 0, 255), text_rect, pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MAX)
```

#### Option 3: use sdl2 blitter

replace:

```
win.blit(text, text_rect)
```

with:

```
win.blit(text, text_rect, special_flags=pygame.BLEND_ALPHA_SDL2)
```

Since this also is about 4 times faster, in an informal test on my Macbook Air, using 1080p surfaces, this might be a good option?

#### Addendum: Checking win for alpha channel

As for why the screen even has an alpha channel, when only the source surface should affect writing stuff, I'm not sure. But you can see it has one, by running:

```
print('win has srcalpha', win.get_flags() & pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

Since the output is non-zero, you can see that `win` has an alpha channel:

```
win has srcalpha 65536
```

Comment: Thanks! Its been a while and I had same problem again, this is really helpful…

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the text, it is with [`pygame.Surface.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill). Replace

<s>`win.fill(0)`</s>

```py
win.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

This is a known bug in the MacOS version of Pygame 2.1.0 and will be fixed in Pygame 2.1.1.
See [Fix weird MacOS display surf weirdness #2859](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2859).

Comment: This will be fixed in Pygame 2.1.1. https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2859

Comment: I have pygame 2.1.2, and I still have the bug :P